# Value of symbol c-basic-offset in a function

Tags: indentation, style

I am using a [mode](https://github.com/sakari/robot-mode) that has the following construct:

```
(defun robot-indent()
  "Returns the string used in indation.
Set indent-tabs-mode to non-nil to use tabs in indentation. If indent-tabs-mode is 
set to nil c-basic-offset defines how many spaces are used for indentation. If c-basic-offset is
not set 4 spaces are used.
 "
 (if indent-tabs-mode
     "\t"
   (make-string (if (boundp 'c-basic-offset) 
                    c-basic-offset 4)
        ?\ )
   )
 )
```

The attempt to use `c-basic-offset` if it is defined (bound?) fails. Evaluating `c-basic-offset` return `set-from-style` instead of 4.

I've tried to replace it with `(symbol-value c-basic-offset)`, but it didn't change anything.

I've read about [style variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Style-Variables.html), but didn't get everything. I set `c-basic-offset` only in custom C style definitions in my init file.

Several questions:

- How do I fix it?
- Is this something that worked in older versions of emacs?

Emacs 24.5.1

Comment: Keep in mind that an `if` statement might return `nil` (depending upon how it is written), and any function that uses that returned value must be able to utilize a `nil` value.  So, the first thing I asked myself is what would happen if the first argument to `make-string` is `nil`?  It is probably not an answer to your question, but is nevertheless something you should consider when this situation exists.

Answer (score 1):

Re-reading about [style variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Style-Variables.html), I assumed `boundp` was not doing what I expected. I guess this function was written before CC mode 5.26, and that it's what footnote 1 in the link above refers too.

Now, `c-basic-offset` is automatically set to `set-from-style` if not globally set.

I changed the function to this and got it working as I expect:

```
(defun robot-indent()
  "Returns the string used in indation.
Set indent-tabs-mode to non-nil to use tabs in indentation. If indent-tabs-mode is 
set to nil c-basic-offset defines how many spaces are used for indentation. If c-basic-offset is
not set 4 spaces are used.
 "
 (if indent-tabs-mode
     "\t"
   (make-string (if (eq c-basic-offset 'set-from-style)
                    4 c-basic-offset)
        ?\ )
   )
 )
```

Comment: `(boundp 'c-basic-offset)` will return `nil` before `c-basic-offset` gets a value (typically by loading cc-mode). And trying to get the value of `c-basic-offset` (like you do in your function) will signal a `void-variable` error.